# Does Redis "EXPIRE" command flush current lifetime of the key?

Tags: redis

Consider we have existing key, say `key1` with not empty value in `Redis`. Consider it has already set expiration time.

If we call `EXPIRE` command on this key again, during this expiration period, say `EXPIRE key1 10`, will it flush current lifetime of that key?

By "*lifetime*" I mean not expiration period,  but current counter of how long this particular key already exists in memory
To be precise, e.g.:

At 10:00 am we call:

```
SET key1 "Blabla"
EXPIRE key1 600
```

At 10:05 am we call

```
EXPIRE key1 600
```

At which time `key1` will expire - at 10:10 am or at 10:15 am?

Comment: @ItamarHaber the question is not about who wins

Comment: @ItamarHaber In any case I've already checked it and provided correct answer, see below

Comment: Last expire wins in the sense the calling `EXPIRE` overwrites any previous TTL if it was set. Good that you experimented to find the answer, but as @ezain answered this is actually documented ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it flushes it indeed. It can be checked directly in `redis-cli` console:

```
EXPIRE key1 600
(integer) 1
TTL key1
(integer) 598
TTL key1
(integer) 569
```

Set expiration again, and we see, that ttl increased:

```
EXPIRE key1 600
(integer) 1
TTL key1
(integer) 597
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly explained in the official documentation

http://redis.io/commands/expire#refreshing-expires

> It is possible to call EXPIRE using as argument a key that already has
>   an existing expire set. **In this case the time to live of a key is
>   updated to the new value.** There are many useful applications for this,
>   an example is documented in the Navigation session pattern section
>   below.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're asking about doesn't exist. A key doesn't have "lifetime", it has an expiration time. If you use `EXPIREAT`, it sets the expiration time to an exact time. If you use `EXPIRE`, it sets the expiration time to a number of seconds after the `EXPIRE` command is run. There is no "counter of how long this particular key already exists in memory"; there is only the current time and the expiration time. As long as the current time is less than the expiration time, the key isn't expired yet. Whenever you use `EXPIRE` or `EXPIREAT` it changes the expiration time, and any previous value no longer matters.